# Eventstore doesn't work in Kubernetes (but works in Docker)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, eventstoredb

I want to run Eventstore in Kubernetes node. I start the node with `minikube start`, then I apply this yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eventstore-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eventstore
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eventstore
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: eventstore
        image: eventstore/eventstore
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1113
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 2113
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eventstore
spec:
  selector:
    app: eventstore
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1113
    targetPort: 1113
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eventstore-dashboard
spec:
  selector:
    app: eventstore
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 2113
    targetPort: 2113
    nodePort: 30113
  type: NodePort
```

the deployment, the replica set and the pod starts, but nothing happens: Eventstore doesn't print to the log, I can't open its dashboard. Also other services can't connect to *eventstore:1113*. No errors and the pods doesn't crash.
The only I see in logs is "The selected container has not logged any messages yet".

[image]
[image]

I've tried a clean vanilla minukube node with different vm drivers, and also a node with configured Ambassador + Linkerd. The results are the same.

But when I run Eventstore in Docker with this yaml file via *docker-compose*

```
eventstore:
    image: eventstore/eventstore
    ports:
      - '1113:1113'
      - '2113:2113'
```

Everything works fine: Eventstore outputs to logs, other services can connect to it and I can open its dashboard on 2113 port.

**UPDATE:** Eventstore started working after about 30-40 minutes after deployment. I've tried several times, and had to wait. Other pods start working almost immediately (30 secs - 1 min) after deployment.

Comment: Could you provide more information? I've tried to reproduce your case however everything is working properly for me.
Did you have enough resources on minikube? Are you tried this on bare metal or cloud provider?

Comment: Maybe specifying the resources(higher values than those by default), cpu and memory on the yaml file?

Comment: @PjoterS yes, the issue was with VM performance. Now I'm using Kind instead Minikube, and everything works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ligowsky confirmed in comment section, issue was cause due to VM Performance. Posting this as Community Wiki for better visibility.

`Minikube` as default is running with `2 CPUs` and `2048 Memory`. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/232080ae0cbcf9cb9a388eb76cc11cf6884e19c0/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go#L103).

You can change this if your VM has more resources.

**- During Minikube start**

```
$ sudo minikube start --cpus 2 --memory 8192 --vm-driver=<driverType>
```

**- When Minikube is running, however minikube need to be restarted**

```
$ minikube config set memory 4096
⚠️  These changes will take effect upon a minikube delete and then a minikube start
```

More commands can be found in [Minikube docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/examples/).

In my case when `Minikube` resources was 4CPUs and 8192 memory I didn't have any issues with `eventstore`.

**OP's Solution**

OP used [Kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) to run `eventstore` deployment.

> Kind is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker
>   container "nodes". kind is primarily designed for testing Kubernetes
>   1.11+

`Kind` documentation can be found [here](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/).